# "<\div>" text inside <div> tag

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a jsp, that is initialized by java method `init()`.

Init is like

```
void init() {
....
out.print("<div>");
out.print(someString);
out.print("</div>");
....
}
```

When `someString` contains `"string</div>"` I get only `"string"` text on my jsp, but I want to get `"string</div>"`. How should I print `"</div>"` text inside `<div>` tags in html?

Comment: Did you try to surround it with the `<pre>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `someString` is not meant to be interpreted as HTML, you don't want to output it literally as HTML, you need to ensure that `<` and `&` are encoded (at least).

You can do that by doing a pair of `String#replace`:

```
out.print(someString.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;"));
```

Note that it's important to do the `&` replacements before the `<` replacement (since otherwise you'll end up encoding the `&` in `&lt;`).

If there's any chance you'll be outputting this inside an attribute value (e.g., `<div data-stuff="output goes here">`), you also want to encode `"`:

```
out.print(
    someString.replace("&", "&amp;")
               .replace("<", "&lt;")
               .replace("\"", "&quot;")
);
```

...and other than a *trivial* increase in the size of your HTML, it's harmless to always encode `"`.

If you use single quotes around attributes (`<div data-stuff='output goes here'>`), you'll also want to encode `'`. I don't know how good browser support for `&apos;` is these days (it used to be spotty), so you might use `&#39;`. My preference is just to ensure that I always use double quotes around the attribute value, so I don't have to worry about apostrophes.

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, that's part of why I gave an example. Since `&apos;` wasn't in the HTML4 spec and many browsers didn't implement it (back in the day), I got used to always using `"` for attributes.